# What's the fastest way to load data into JavaScript in a static website for immediate use?

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js, datatable

I have a website that needs to load a big quantity of data (i.e. ~5 or 10 Mb in CSV).

It's a static website (HTML and JS only, no databases) and I need all the data at once from the beginning because I use the data in [dc.js](https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/) and [datatables](http://www.datatables.net/).

For now I have stored the data in a CSV file and I load it with the `d3.csv` function from [d3.js](https://d3js.org/).
But with 20k records on my fastest connection it takes 5 sec. just to load the file.

To give a better idea, here is a single record of my CSV (which has 10k to 50k of these):

```
Title,Year,Rating,NumVotes,imdbID,Type,poster_path,release_date,Released,Runtime,Genres,Directors,Actors,Plot,Country,Metascore,imdbRating,imdbVotes,tomatoMeter,tomatoReviews,tomatoUserMeter,tomatoUserReviews,DVD
"Grease Live!","2016","7.7","3978","tt4366830","TV Movie","/6g1E0Ptg27NLCoK7rhJxuQxZCdg.jpg","2016-01-31","31 Jan 2016","180","Musical","Thomas Kail, Alex Rudzinski","Aaron Tveit, Julianne Hough, Elle McLemore, Vanessa Hudgens","After enjoying a summer romance, high school students Danny and Sandy are unexpectedly reunited when she transfers to Rydell High. There Sandy must contend with cynical Rizzo and the Pink Ladies in attempt to win Danny's heart again.","USA","N/A","7.8","3,710","N/A","N/A","N/A","12","N/A"
```

I would like to know what would be the fastest way to load my data (compress, split and async load, firebase...).

All I know for the moment is that JSON is worse than CSV because it takes more space.

Comment: Is it gzipped already? Not sure how well it works for your data, but better than nothing.

Comment: The fastest would be to have a subset of the data you need. Do you really need all those data on the page?

Comment: You have asked this same question before...nothing has changed since last week when lots of alternatives were given to you. the fact that you insist on loading all that data at once is still silly. You are sacrificing big page loads for the sake of inconsequential server side search time

Comment: As @charlietfl says, you have already [asked this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35461462/whats-the-fastest-way-to-load-data-into-javascript-in-a-static-website-for-d3-a). In fact, it received votes to reopen after you edited it. Next time, wait for the original question to work its way through the review queues; don't ask a duplicate question.

Comment: You could chunck the data and do parallel downloading - or look into compressing the data with something like gzip.

https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/optimizing-content-efficiency/optimize-encoding-and-transfer?hl=en

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## 1. Break up the data

Maybe you can break the data into chunks of a few thousand rows, to be rebuilt client side before being passed to datatables?

This way you can leverage parallel downloads.

## 2. Leverage client side caching

If you know how frequently the data will change, or can accept certain intervals of change, you can use HTTP `Expires` headers to keep the file from being unnecessarily downloaded?

Just shots in the dark here

Answer (score 1):

Maybe look into this http://papaparse.com

There is an online demo that you might be able to just paste your data into and see how long it takes.  Download the script and try it out and compare it to what you are using.

Comment: While this may answer the question, it is better to provide the actual information here and not just a link. [Link-only answers are not considered good answers and will probably be deleted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).